# Windows 10 Disk Manager Showing Disk That Doesn't Exist

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, disk-management

I only have two drives in my computer (not including my optical drive), a 1TB SSD and a 6TB HDD. However, Disk Management says that I have a third drive, an empty 3540.91 GB drive with no volumes.

Just for fun, I have tried making a volume on the drive, but it returns an error message saying "Incorrect function." It makes perfect sense that the drive can't do anything (since it doesn't actually exist), but why is it showing up in the first place?

If it means anything, I had a defective 4TB drive (about 3.5TB usable) in my machine previously, but I replaced it with the 6TB (since it was defective). To make sure I'm clear, I am holding the 4TB drive as I type this. It is not in my machine, or in any way plugged into my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**delete the disk in disk manager**

It's advertising it's ID in case in 'comes back' and it will be recognized as it was previously and mounted during the boot process.

If you get a rid of a drive altogether for whatever reason, just dump it in disk manager if your not going to put it back in.